# MaxMind GeoIP is different across servers (WordPress Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, geoip, maxmind

I am using the MaxMind GeoIP WordPress plugin with the lite DB. I have a staging site and a production site.

Within the plugin options, you can hit 'IP Test' - which should read my IP and show my location. On staging, it reads my IP and correct location. On production, it tests against a private IP address that returns incorrect location info. I suspect this IP is what the production site thinks ALL visitor traffic comes from, as it is returning erroneous data for all users.

The live site is hosted on Amazon EC2, yet the server IP is different from the phantom that my production GeoIP THINKS that all visitors are coming from.

Comment: It would be useful to post the plugin you're using. Presumably it pulls the IP from PHP's REMOTE_ADDR which may be wrongly populated if your server is behind some kind of proxy.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this site is using Varnish CDN on the production server. The phantom IP is owned by them, and routes all traffic through this. Of course, the GeoIP cannot work if it is being shunted to a 'nearby' node.